# How to send data to openfire xmpp server from python and receive it in xmpp client such as spark?

Tags: python, xmpp, openfire

I want to send a message to an openfire xmpp server and receive the message in xmpp client such as spark, conversejs etc.

```java
   import sys
   import os
   import xmpp`

   `msg = "Hello World!"
   jid = "derrick@ec2-3-14-139-186.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com" 
   pwd = "123456789"
   recipient = "derry@ec2-3-14-139-186.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com"
   jid = xmpp.protocol.JID(jid)
   cl = xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain(), debug=[])
   if cl.connect() == "":
       print("not connected")
   sys.exit(0)
   if cl.auth(jid.getNode(), pwd) == None:
       print("authentication failed")
   sys.exit(0)
   cl.send(xmpp.protocol.Message(recipient, msg))
   cl.disconnect()
```

I have installed the xmpppy library and receive the following error that some modules do not exist:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/XMPP_Test8/test.py", line 3, in <module> import xmpp File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\XMPP_Test8\venv\lib\site-packages\xmpp_init_.py", line 29, in <module> import simplexml,protocol,debug,auth,transports,roster,dispatcher,features,browser,filetransfer,commands ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simplexml'`

Comment: What have you tried yet? Did you read some documentation? We will be happy to help you with buggy code but we can not provide a working solution including a wholesome conceptual explanation I am afraid.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly...

Comment: Please check it now.

Comment: What error do you get? Maybe we can help you install the missing modules.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/XMPP_Test8/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import xmpp
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\XMPP_Test8\venv\lib\site-packages\xmpp\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import simplexml,protocol,debug,auth,transports,roster,dispatcher,features,browser,filetransfer,commands
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simplexml'

Comment: Is simplexml installed? I do not know that module but can you pip it in or activate it in xmpp?

Comment: If I pip install simplexml , I get **"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement simplexml (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for simplexml"**

Comment: So can you activate it from xmpp? Must be available somewhere...